# How to solve bitwise error in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, modis, time-series

I've wrote the below code for chlorophyll detection using MODIS ocean reflectance data but I've got this error:

> Image.bitwiseXor: Bitwise operands must be integer only.

[image]

code link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/31dc6a60f330ee27c8e2a3e75eddee3c

```
Map.centerObject(table);
Map.addLayer(table);

var chl = modis
.filterDate('2020-05-01','2020-06-01')
.filterBounds(table)
.map(function(img){
  var bands = img.multiply(0.0001).clip(table);
  
  var R = bands.expression('log(b9 / b12)',
  {'b9': bands.select('sur_refl_b09'),'b12': bands.select('sur_refl_b12')});
  
  var index = bands.expression('10.0 ^ (0.283 + (-2.753 * R) + (1.457 * R^2) + (0.659 * R^3) + (-1.403 * R^4))'
  ,{'R':R});
  
  return index.copyProperties(img,['system:time_start','system:time_end']);
}).mean();



print(chl);
Map.addLayer(chl);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`^` is not the exponent operator, `**` is (`^` is xor).  See https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_math:

[image]

Hence this line:

`var index = bands.expression('10.0 ^ (0.283 + (-2.753 * R) + (1.457 * R^2) + (0.659 * R^3) + (-1.403 * R^4))' ,{'R':R});`

should read:

`var index = bands.expression('10.0**(0.283 + (-2.753 * R) + (1.457 * R**2) + (0.659 * R**3) + (-1.403 * R**4))' ,{'R':R});`